# Extract a variable and add it to a separate XML file

Tags: xml, perl

I have a script that logs in and returns a session ID. I need the session ID so that I can populate an XML file to do stuff with it, for example create a plant room for a nursery.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $authenticate = do {
    open my $fh, '<', '/tmp/login.xml' or die "Could not open file: $!";
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

my $webpage = "https://www.example.com/api";

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->post($webpage, Content_Type => 'text/xml',
                                        Content => $authenticate);


if ( $response->is_success) {

    my $xml = new XML::Simple;
    my $x = $response->decoded_content;

    # read XML file
    my $data = $xml->XMLin($x);

    my $sessionid =  $data->{'sessionid'};

...
```

I need to take that sessionid variable and insert into another xml file that looks like this:

```xml
<xml>
  <API>4.0</API>
  <action>plant_room_add</action>
  <enforce_rules_training>0</enforce_rules_training>
  <id>3</id>
  <location>123456</location>
  <name>Test1</name>
  <sessionid>$sessionid</sessionid>
  <signature>Hello World</signature>
  <terminal_id>xxxxxxx</terminal_id>
  <training>1</training>
</xml>
```

I know that I can put the `plant_root_add` XML in the same script, but I think this script is growing to grow over time so I might need a script to delete the plant room. This is for monitoring and it will be executed every 60 seconds.

What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Do not use](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE) `XML::Simple`.  Both [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) and [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm) are far better, to say the least.

I can't show how to pull data from the first XML since it's not shown, but here is how to edit that other XML file using `XML::LibXML`. I suggest to rewrite the first operation with this module as well.

Find the node via an [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression and replace element's text-node children: remove and add.

```
use warnings;
use strict;    
use XML::LibXML;

# ... your code that establishes the $session_id variable ...
my $session_id = 'SAMPLE_ID';
my $filename = 'another.xml';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);

my ($node) = $doc->findnodes('//sessionid');
$node->removeChildNodes();
$node->appendText($session_id);    

# print $doc->toString;
$doc->toFile('edited_' . $filename);  # or just $filename to overwrite
```

Documentation on [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) most relevant to this is for [Text](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Text.pod), [Element](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Element.pod), and [Node](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod) classes. See also pages for [Parser](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod) and [Document](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Document.pod). Here is `XPath` [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/?cm_mc_uid=16760443233414162548406&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1481249745) and a [tutorial (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).

---

A few comments.

Instead of loading the file directly we can create the parser object first

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($filename);
```

With the parser on hand we can use methods for [its configuration](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Parser.pod#PARSER_OPTIONS) outside of the constructor (while stilll before parsing), what provides more flexibility.

There are other ways to change data, depending on your purpose. For example

```
$node->firstChild->setData($session_id);
```

is more specific. It uses `firstChild` from [XML::LibXML::Node](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0128/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod)

> If a node has child nodes this function will return the first node in the child list.

and `setData` from [XML::LibXML::Text](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Text.pod)

> This function sets or replaces text content to a node. The node has to be of the type "text", "cdata" or "comment".

This works for that one child, "*the first node in the child list*."

We can also get the text node by `findnodes('//sessionid/text()')` and use `setData` (on that one child) directly, if the element has children. You probably want to do as in the answer though.